# Does the Rebuild button retrigger a build using the same logic as the original build, or does it use the latest jobspec?

Tags: palantir-foundry

Specifically, I'm referring to this button on the build overview screen:

[Build button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNLfa.png)

Answer (score 2):

It will build the dataset using the latest jobspec.